# React - How to make CSS class more selective and override default class?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am starting with React but have some background in web prior to it.

I have a default component let's say `.title`, I would like to override few things from it, maybe the `background-color` or the `font-size` for the situation where it is in this specific page.

In "normal" web, I would simply write a class `.special-page .title` or `.title.special-version` and override what I want.

From what I have read, because of the module CSS system of react, this is not possible. I am using `scss` and I can't even use nested classes which is a pain but I got used to it.

What is the correct way to do this ?

I tried with `classNames` and do `cn(defaultStyle.title, styles.special_title)` but the priority seems random over which of the css class is expressed based on the order of `import` and the order of the class in `cn`.

Is there a reliable way to have one class modifying a base one without having to put `!important` everywhere ?

Thank you !

Comment: "From what I have read, because of the module CSS system of react, this is not possible" — You heard wrong. (React has lots of modular CSS systems and I'm not aware of any that that applies to)

Comment: "I am using scss and I can't even use nested classes which is a pain but I got used to it." — Every system I've used to bring SCSS into a React app has supported nested classes.

Comment: "I tried with classNames and do cn(defaultStyle.title, styles.special_title) but the priority seems random over which of the css class is expressed based on the order of import and the order of the class in cn." — No. The order of classes in the class attribute is irrelevant. [The normal cascading rules apply](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade).

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, would you mind typing an answer that explains those ? Which stack are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you interpreted the css module incorrectly. All the classes you have defined in module.css will only affect the respective component. This is because when rendering a component react takes the class name you defined and manipulates them by adding a hash on it (to make it component specific). to use generic class names import the css as regular import (not as module.css but filename.css). the generic css classes will be available throughout the entire app if you placc then in index.js or App.js

Now, you can define your `.title` in generic css and `.special-version` in  module. Then use them  both in class name as regular html `title special-version`. It will take both `.title` styles and `.special-version` style. place those rules, you want to override, in `.special-version`

Comment: I have tried this. But then in some cases, the `.title` overrides `.special-version` instead of the other way around